# How to set ulimit to unlimited in perl?

Tags: linux, perl, ulimit

I want all child processes of my perl script to generate core files in case of unexpected failures. So how can I set `ulimit` to `unlimited` inside perl?

Comment: Try BDS::Resource.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226329/how-do-i-set-a-ulimit-from-inside-a-perl-script-that-applies-to-its-children

Comment: I don't wan't to use external dependencies.

Comment: can you explain why not?

Comment: The script is a part of our distribution. So taking into account that not small part of perl distributions doesn't support BDS we sometimes will have to ask to our costumers to install a new perl distribution which is not enough good.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the openfiles parameters of the user that launch your perl script. So you can change the limit on-the-fly with:

```
ulimit -n unlimited && perl path/to/your/script.pl
```

Or you can make a bash script `foo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ulimit -n unlimited
perl path/to/your/script.pl
```

Comment: On most systems, such `ulimit` operation requires `root` permissions.