# How do you prevent perl from making a dump file?

Tags: perl, bash, perl-module

Currently I am running several scripts which are in a experimental testing stage. Unfortunately they crash on occasion and generate large "core-perl-11-544-546-27320-1xxxxxxx" perl core dump files.

I want to ensure that if in the future these files crash again, they do not generate perl dump files, or the files size of the dump is limited.

Right now there are some scripts checking for Perl core dump files and removing them if they are greater than a set size, but this is an obvious band-aid on a broken knee.

**How might I go about limiting the size of the perl dump file, or preventing one from being made?**

Comment: You will want to take a look at [ulimit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) in bash.

Comment: that should be an answer, @j.w.r

Comment: the broken knee is that perl is dumping core at all.  it shouldn't, you know.  are you perhaps using threads and a non-threadsafe module?

Comment: @ysth yep, I have threads currently running. Occasionally when 20,000 threads are started at once is when the error most commonly occurs.

Comment: @BeauBouchard, twenty-thousand threads? You need to reevaluate your design. Perl's threading support is not so very great.

Comment: @titanofold I am discovering this :/ we have redesigned the architecture and are doing a different approach. :D

Comment: @BeauBouchard, for the record, I have used both threads and fork. Both have their challenges. I have a script that successfully and reliably uses 3 threads. I had another that had all kinds of trouble with bleed-over. Fork is very clean but is limited to systems that can fork(), and sharing data requires an external resource.

Comment: Perl's threading support is ok, they just are *not* lightweight threads as many other languages have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the creation of a core dump file from within the perl script, you can use (procedure stolen from [How do I set a ulimit from inside a Perl script that applies to its children?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8272239/2413201)):

```
require 'syscall.ph';
require 'sys/resource.ph';
$rstruct = pack "L!L!",0,&RLIM_INFINITY;
syscall(&SYS_setrlimit,&RLIMIT_CORE,$rstruct);
```

To limit dumps to a certain size, change the `0` above to the desired size.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't

use BSD::Resource;
  setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, 0, 0);

be simpler?