# how does perl invoke "ulimit -n"

Tags: perl, shell

1. `ulimit -n` is an internal shell that perl cannot invoke by `system` or ``` `` ``` directly. so how does perl deal with it when I want to get ulimit value
2. Do `ulimit -n` and `sh -c ulimit -n` have the different values. When I use `ulimit -n` the value is 1024 but when I `sh -c ulimit -n` the value is unlimited.

Comment: Could you post the perl code your question is about? Perl doesn't have a `ulimit` operation.

Comment: use BSD::Resource;$rlimit = getrlimit("RLIMIT_OPEN_MAX");

Answer (score 4):

For question #2, you need to quote the command:

```
sh -c 'ulimit -n'
```

The way you did it is equivalent to:

```
sh -n -c ulimit
```

and `ulimit` with no option is equivalent to `ulimit -f`.

Answer (score 1):

For your first Question check here:

[Set ulimit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226329/how-do-i-set-a-ulimit-from-inside-a-perl-script-that-applies-to-its-children)

For second point,

Use as:

```
sh -c 'ulimit -n'
```

If you check man pages:

> If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.  If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

Comment: Thanks very much！The first seems use BSD::Resource can solve.

Answer (score 1):

A program doesn't have to use `ulimit` to get the maximum number of open file descriptors — indeed, `ulimit` has to be getting that value from somewhere else!  The Perl function `BSD::Resource::getrlimit` is just invoking a C function named, surprisingly, [`getrlimit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getrlimit.html) and using it to retrieve the value directly from the operating system, the same way that `ulimit` gets it.